# Can't remove whitespace from underneath Navigation bar

Tags: html, css

so on my test page I'm having this issue with the navigation bar. There's whitespace that appears underneath and it is being caused by a hidden button and drop down menu.

In full desktop view, top right you will see Select Province/Ontario and Francais, when the website goes into mobile view, I hide those two, and then in the Navigation bar, i have two buttons and a drop down menu appear.

I have tried using visbility: hidden and currently using display: none;, and have tried using both together, but no luck.

It's weird, if I shrink the screen down it only looks like there's one hidden li after maximizing.

BUT if you shrink down and open the toggle menu, and then maximize without closing it, it'll show you the two extra whitespace underneath it. If i removed the Francais and Province sections it would work perfect, but unfortunately i need them lol.

Here is the html:

```
<nav>
  <div>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="left"><a href="http://convio.cancer.ca/site/TR?fr_id=[[S80:trID]]" class="home-btn" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a href="TR/Events?pg=informational&amp;type=fr_informational&amp;sid=9700&amp;fr_id=[[S80:trID]]" class="tours-btn" title="Register">Register</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a href="TR/Events?pg=pfind&amp;fr_id=[[S80:trID]]" class="about-btn" title="Search participants or teams">Find a Fundraiser</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a href="TR/Events/General?pg=informational&fr_id=21282&type=fr_informational&sid=6583" class="learn-btn" title="Learn more">Learn More</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="TR/Events?pg=pfind&amp;fr_id=[[S80:trID]]" class="donater-btn hvr-buzz-out" title="Donate to team or participant">DONATE</a></li>

   <li class="dropdown">
     <a class="dropdown-toggle provinces-btn" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Province<span class="caret"></span></a> 
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Alberta</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">British Columbia</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Ontario</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Nunavut</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Manitoba</a></li>
    </ul>  
   </li>

   <li class="right"><a href="frenchurl" class="french-btn" title="French">Français</a></li>

  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the css for those two extra `<li>`:

```
/*Mobile provinces Selector*/
@media screen and (min-width: 769px){
 .provinces-btn{
  display: none;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.provinces-btn {

    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: #0066CC;
    margin-left: 0px;


}

    .provinces-btn:hover, .provinces-btnActive {
        color: #FFEE00 !important;
        background: #1975D1;
        font-weight: 900;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 604px) {
.provinces-btn {

    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: #0066CC;
    margin-left: 15px;

   }

       .provinces-btn:hover, .provinces-btnActive {
        color: #FFEE00 !important;
        background: #1975D1;
        font-weight: 900;
    }

 }



/*French BTN*/
@media screen and (min-width: 769px){
 .french-btn{
  display: none;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.french-btn {

    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: #0066CC;
    margin-left: 0px;


}

    .french-btn:hover, .french-btnActive {
        color: #FFEE00 !important;
        background: #1975D1;
        font-weight: 900;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 604px) {
.french-btn {

    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 16px;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color: #0066CC;
    margin-left: 15px;

   }

       .french-btn:hover, .french-btnActive {
        color: #FFEE00 !important;
        background: #1975D1;
        font-weight: 900;
    }

 }
```

thank you for your time!

Comment: I removed them with `display: none !important`. my idea would be to use two different navigation bars - one for mobile and one for regular screen. Easier to maintain.

Comment: that's an excellent idea, I may do that later down the project, its just im under a time constraint atm. but Mikelis! thank you for the !important i forgot all about it. Can you please put that down as the answer and i'll mark it! thank you so much!

Comment: Horrible band aid... fix the issue by using position relative on your container. Your absolute is overflowing and on my screen (desktop) is on the right side no where near the menu (on both 1920x1080 and 2560x1440 screen). In Edge, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: As a developer, I advise not to put your website up on the internet before it is done, it can lead to people abusing the not 100% done functions.

Comment: @Bálint good point i'll have to remove those links now lol

Comment: @SimonHayter that's weird on 1920x1080 was working earlier. I didn't account for 2560x1440 though thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Umeed, it'll happen on all screens until you use relative on your parent container... i.e `#logo-login-container {)` The select box is `right:` of 100% of the screen... and not container... that means right 300px will be different distance on 1920x, than that on 1600px, because the viewpoint is wider.

Comment: Your container is `max-width:970px` so to use absolute the items should use `right; 0,` you can't do this because you have not set `position: relative` and this is what's causing you a headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove them with `display: none !important` to overwrite the `display: block`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is occurring because the parent container does not have `position: relative` and so the child containers are using the full width of the page rather than being contained and behaved. To help you understand what's going on I made this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SimonHayter/6w62hL3s/12/) one with relative on the container, one without it.

```
#logo-login-container {
    height: 135px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 970px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}


.styled-select {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://convio.cancer.ca/mResponsive/images/icons/dropdown_blue_icon.png") no-repeat scroll right center;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    height: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 100px;
    width: 185px;
}
```

Your need to change Français position to `right: 210px;` as this is set outside of the CSS stylesheet. Also in future I recommend that you research css floats as they are much easier to manage.

Comment: oh man thank you for this. I requested 1080p screens but i was rejected so I been working with these really small monitors, so I keep forgetting to check on the 1080p version at my home. But i completely forgot abotu 2560p. I will research css floats and their benefits while i work on this. Thanks again

Comment: No need to test on different monitor size. You should be able to replicate the problem on any size. See my JsFiddle that I just added.

Comment: lol i like the text you used for it. This is good, I'm learning a lot. it's my first job let alone my first assignment so I'm glad you're telling me all of this. I'm taking notes.